# Errors when trying to migrate my InterBase .gdb from version 6 to Xe3

Tags: windows, interbase

I prepared the databases in InterBase 6 and now want to migrate them to InterBase Xe3
but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error Connecting to requested database
message length error (encountered 287, expected 68)
```

Any ideas about what might me causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried backing up the interbase 6 file and restoring it into an empty XE database?

worked for me when converting from interbase 7.5